# stdr_simulatorTutorialsCreate a map with gmapping - "the right topic"?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/stdr_simulator/Tutorials/Create%20a%20map%20with%20gmapping in [section 4](http://wiki.ros.org/stdr_simulator/Tutorials/Create%20a%20map%20with%20gmapping#Run_rviz_to_visualize_the_generated_map) it says:

> After you have subscribed to the correct topic, you should see the generated map by gmapping...

What's the "correct topic" and how do I subscribe to it in Rviz? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280992/stdr_simulatortutorialscreate-a-map-with-gmapping---%22the-right-topic%22?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the correct topic in RViz by

1. Clicking the "Add" button
2. Clicking on the "By topic" tab in the popup
3. Search for the topic under the `/gmapping` node (or whatever name you have given it) that has a message type of `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` (most likely the `/map` topic)
4. Click "Ok"

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1